# Java: txt file into a 2nd array

Tags: java, arrays, file, maze

So, the first problem is how I can get the number of column from the file txt. 
The file is like that:

```
WWWSWW\n  
WWW___\n   
WWWWWW\n  
W_____\n  
WWW_WW\n  
W_____\n  
W_W_W\n  
WE____\n
```

In this example I have 8 rows and 8 columns but I have to extract that from the file.

Another problem is I can't return the array to another class.

My code:

```
File file = new File("maze.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
//contar as linhas
List<String> lines= 
Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("maze.txt"),Charset.defaultCharset());

int noOfLines=lines.size()-1;
char[][] myArray=new char[noOfLines][noOfLines];

//this read the file and make the array
for (int row = 0; scanner.hasNextLine() && row < noOfLines; row++) {
    char[] chars = scanner.nextLine().toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfLines && i < chars.length; i++) {
        myArray[row][i] = chars[i];

    }

}
```

Comment: How do you know there are 8 columns when looking at the file content? Why do you read your file twice, instead of just once: everything is already in memory in the `lines`list. What's the point of reading it a second time?

Comment: When I use lines is to extract the number of lines. And I assume that the number of lines and columns are the same. Then, I  read the file and put in an array bidimensional. Am I correct?

Comment: *I assume that the number of lines and columns are the same*: well that assumption could be right, or it could be wrong. If the file is always supposed to have the same number of lines and columns, then I guess it's fine (although you could verify that it's true and throw a meaningful exception if it's not the case). Otherwise, then you should not make that assumption. But again: why read the file a second time since all its content is alredy available in memory, inside the list of lines?

Comment: @JB Nizet It was my mistake. Can you help me how to acess an array from another class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd read the entire file as you did, and then just use Java 8's streaming capabilities to do all the heavy lifting for you:

```
char[][] maze = lines.stream().map(String::toCharArray).toArray(char[][]::new);
```

Comment: When I do a print to maze shows me the following output:[[C@5910e440.    What is happening?

Comment: @Toshiyuki Arrays in java don't override `toString()`. Try to print each character individually and you'll see it contains the right values.

Comment: @Toshiyuki or use the `Arrays.toString(maze)` utility method, but keep in mind that a multidimensional array in java is an *array of arrays*, therefore you have to loop over the outer array and apply the helper method to its elements.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle that way you said only works with 1D array, to work in 2D array have to be this way :                                                             
                  int[][] array = new int[rows][columns];
                                           
                  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));